# Initialize values of array in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization

I have a struct which has several arrays within it. The arrays have type unsigned char[4].

I can initialize each element by calling

```
struct->array1[0] = (unsigned char) something;
... 
struct->array1[3] = (unsigned char) something;
```

Just wondering if there is a way to initialize all 4 values in one line.

SOLUTION: I needed to create a temporary array with all the values initialized, then call memset() to copy the values to the struct array.

Comment: I must say that this is so well-known that some googling would have revealed the answer quickly...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c

;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the values are the same, you might do something like

```
struct->array[0] = struct->array[1] = struct->array[2] = struct->array[3] = (unsigned char) something;
```

Otherwise, if the values are stored in an array, you can use the [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/) function like so

```
memcpy(struct->array, some_array, sizeof(struct->array));
```

Comment: This was what I needed to do. I had tried creating a temp array and making it equal but I needed to memcpy. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

If you really mean "initialize" in the sense that you can do it at the time you declare the variable, then sure:

```
struct x {
  unsigned char array1[4];
  unsigned char array2[4];
};

struct x mystruct = { 
   { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
   { 5, 6, 7, 8 }
};
```

Comment: I mean more in the sense that once the struct is created to edit each value with the arrays.

Comment: Gotcha - then you can either use `memset()` to set them all to the same value, or make a template array and `memcpy()` it if you want them to be different.  Besides that, pretty much all you can do is assign them one by one.

Comment: This solution is not very likely practical with the given correct syntax. So -1

Answer (score 18):

When you create the struct, you can initialise it with aggregate initialisation:

```
struct test {
    int blah;
    char arr[4];
};

struct test = { 5, { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' } };
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

```
struct Foo
{
    unsigned char a[4];
    unsigned char b[4];
};

struct Foo x = { { 1, 2, 3, 'a' },  { 'a', 'b', 'c', 0 } };
```

Answer (score 3):

I see you have a pointer (do you?).

If you allocate memory for the pointer with `calloc()` everything inside the struct will be initialized with `0`.

Otherwise you need to `memset()` to 0 or assign a value element-by-element.

```
memset(struct_pointer, 0, sizeof *struct_pointer);
```

Comment: Thank you. The memset part is what helped me.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop too:

```
  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) the_struct->array1[i] = (unsigned char) something;
```

This will work even when you have not char but e.g. int (and values != 0). In fact, memsetting to, say, 1 a struct made of int (when sizeof int greater than 1) is not the correct way to initialize them.